# Oracle v$archive_gap returns no rows selected

Tags: oracle, standby

In my DG environment, alert log shows the logs are applied on standby.

Then, I am querying the standby and primary using v$archive_gap. The query returns no rows selected. Because there is no gap? 
Only when there is archive gaps on a standby database, a row is returned??

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the interval of missing arch-files, if none are missing then you will get no rows..

```
select * from v$archive_gap;
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.